# React native how to force/override min width / device dpi for my app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I need to force device dpi to be at least 350px. App is almost unusable with 320dpi devices. I've manually changed dev settings of such devices to higher values and it works ok. Text and other ui stuff is smaller but thats totally acceptable.

**Thats the setting I want to override within react native app:**
[image]

App at 392 dpi:
[image]

At 320 dpi (some screens are worse)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set this setting in the app, all you can do is try to code a [responsive app](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-add-responsivity-to-react-native-apps) using FlexBox and different units of length.

Comment: Thats what I guessed, but maybe there is a way that i could simulatate this? Otherwise adding everywhere something like isScreenWidth320Greater && "font-size:12px" doesn't sound like a good way to go. Or maybe I can make a responsive Text element but thats not optimal either.